# get the integer between the dates

Tags: c#

i am programming in c# and i have question:
how can i get the integer value between a date.
for example : 12/6/2010 and 12/18/2010
how can i get at 1st i=6 and in the second i=18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("12/6/2010");
int i = dt.Day;
```

See: [DateTime reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking, but you can access the day from a DateTime as follows:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;
int day=dt.Day;
```

If you want a time difference in days:

```
DateTime dt1=new DateTime(2010,12,6);
DateTime dt2=new DateTime(2010,12,18);
int dayDelta=(dt2-dt1).Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DateTime variable (birth, by example). you can use birth.Month to obtain the month, birth.Day to obtain the day, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Days" method of `DateTime` class.